# If some polynomial is in an ideal $I$, how can I write it as a linear combination of the generators of $I$?

Tags: commutative-algebra

I'm looking for a (easy) procedure of some sort. I also know a little bit of Singular and CoCoA, and was wondering if you can do that in there?

Comment: There is no 'easy' procedure. You can do this with Groebner bases.

Comment: @MooS Okay, but I want a linear combination in terms of the given generators of $I$, not a combination in the polynomials of the Groebner basis.

Comment: When you produce a Gröbner basis of $I$ you can keep track of the progress, and will then know how to write the elements of the resulting Gröbner basis in terms of the original set of generators.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It's sometimes not very easy to compute a basis by hand, so if I'm using a computer to find a Groebner basis, how do I keep track of  everything then?

Comment: As I said: There is no easy procedure.

Comment: You could of course let the computer only do the division algorithms and keep track of the S-polynomials by hand (or by a self-written script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how in Macaulay2.

Let's say your ideal is $I=(x^2+2y^2-3,y^2-yx)$.

Then I claim that $y^3-y$ is in the ideal. Then we can write

```
i59 : f

       2     2
o59 = x  + 2y  - 3

o59 : R

i60 : g

               2
o60 = - x*y + y

o60 : R

i61 : f = x^2+2*y^2-3

       2     2
o61 = x  + 2y  - 3

o61 : R

i62 : g = y^2-x*y

               2
o62 = - x*y + y

o62 : R

i63 : I = ideal(f,g)

              2     2               2
o63 = ideal (x  + 2y  - 3, - x*y + y )

o63 : Ideal of R

i64 : (y^3-y) // gens I

o64 = {2} | 1/3y      |
      {2} | 1/3x+1/3y |

              2       1
o64 : Matrix R  <--- R
```

Hence we see that $y^3-y = \frac 13 f +\frac 13(x+y)g$.

Comment: in $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$ when $k =\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ it reduces to solving a system of linear equations ?

Comment: @user1952009 Well, yes, but you don't a priori know the degree of $a,b$ in $af+bg$, so that you don't know a priori how big a system you  must solve.

Comment: I didn't notice that problem, can the degree of $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ really be arbitrary big with respect to the degree of $P \in I$ ?